# how to convert nested array of objects to object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have got  array of nested array of objects .

```
  const data = [ {group: [{label:"1"}]}, {topGroup: [{label:"2"}]} ]
```

I want to convert array to this format of objects and I want to get this output

```
 let permission ={

       group:["1"],
       topGroup:["2"]
     }
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: You can use reduce or map method for data array. But what is the algorithm to become "2" from "12"?

Comment: const data = [ {group: ["1"]}, {topGroup: ["12"]} ]
 let da = Object.fromEntries(data.map((key)=>Object.entries(key)[0])) I got value when when My input data , but I could not understand when I add object inside array  . how can I get my expected output

Comment: I just edited . can you see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [ {group: [{label:"1"}]}, {topGroup: [{label:"2"}]} ]

const converted = data.reduce((a,b) => {
   const onlyKey = Object.keys(b)[0];
   a[onlyKey] = b[onlyKey].map(i => i.label);
   return a;
}, {})

console.log(converted)
```

Comment: can you look this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829455/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment107622910_60829455

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [ {group: [{label:"1"}]}, {topGroup: [{label:"2"}]} ]
let permission = {};
data.forEach(val =>{
  for(prop in val){
    permission[prop] = [val[prop][0]["label"]]
  }
})

console.log(permission)
```

Give this a upvote if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is going to have `label`s as in that format forever, you could use something like that

```js
const data = [{"group":[{"label":"1"}]},{"topGroup":[{"label":"12"}]}];

// The dict variable under here is the second parameter of reduce that I passed it `{}`.
// The ind variable is the data at the index of the array.
var newData = data.reduce(function(dict, ind){
    // You basically get the keys and the values and put them in place
    // and return the last state to the reduce function.
    dict[Object.keys(ind)] = Object.values(ind)[0][0]["label"];
    return dict;
}, {})

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use destructuring and `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
const data = [{ group: [{ label: "1" }] }, { topGroup: [{ label: "2" }] }];

const permission = Object.fromEntries(
  data.map(item => {
    const [[key, [obj]]] = Object.entries(item);
    return [key, Object.values(obj)];
  })
);

console.log(permission);
```

Comment: I am really trouble this problem . can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829455/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment107622910_60829455