# How to filtering array of objects to another array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, object

I have got two arrays of objects . I want to filtering data based on PermissionObj.

This is coming form database. Here is arrays of sub-arrays in the permissionObj .

```
    const PermissionObj = {
     permission: [{
       "books": [{
        "label": "Can View",
        "value": "can_view"
       }]
      },
      {
       "Journals": [{
         "label": "Can View",
         "value": "can_view"
        },
        {
         "label": "Can Create",
         "value": "can_create"
        },
       ]
      },
      {
       "deal": [{
         "label": "Can update",
         "value": "can_update"
        },
        {
         "label": "Can delete",
         "value": "can_delete"
        },
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
```

this is static data. I want to compare this data based on PermissionObj.

```
const data = [{
  label: "books",
  value: "can_view"
 },
 {
  label: "deal",
  content: [{

   value: "can_update"
  }, {
   value: "can_delete"
  },{value:"can_view"}]
 },
 {
  label: "Articles",

 },
 {
  label: "Journals",
  content: [{
    value: "can_create"
   },
   {
    value: "can_view"
   },
  {
    value: "can_delete"
   },
 {
    value: "can_edit"
   },

  ]
 }
]
```

I am trying filter **data array of object** based on **PermissionObj array of objects** . here is my trying code.

```
let permission = PermissionObj.permission 

permission.filter(item=>{
  // I am finding data label by using permission label.

 let dataItem = data.find(index=>item[index.label])

 console.log(dataItem)

})

  // the problem is that I want to filtering based on value .

  // if both of value is true , then show the data .
```

if PermissionObj value will be matched with data value . then show the data .
My accepted Output would be this format :

```
const data = [{
  label: "books",
  value: "can_view"
 },
 {
  label: "deal",
  content: [{
   value: "can_update"
  }, {
   value: "can_delete"
  }]
 },
 {
  label: "Journals",
  content: [{
    value: "can_create"
   },
   {
    value: "can_view"
   },


  ]
 }
]
```

Comment: I see the output is undefined

Comment: filter returns an array so you need to assign it to a variable `let filtered = permission.filter...`

Comment: you look this . I am really trouble this issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First build `keys` from PermissionObj. Use filter on data array which label includes in `keys`.

```js
const PermissionObj = {
  permission: [
    {
      books: [
        {
          label: "Can View",
          value: "can_view"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      Journals: [
        {
          label: "Can View",
          value: "can_view"
        },
        {
          label: "Can Create",
          value: "can_create"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      deal: [
        {
          label: "Can update",
          value: "can_update"
        },
        {
          label: "Can delete",
          value: "can_delete"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const data = [
  {
    label: "books",
    value: "can_view"
  },
  {
    label: "deal",
    content: [
      {
        value: "can_update"
      },
      {
        value: "can_delete"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "Articles"
  },
  {
    label: "Journals",
    content: [
      {
        value: "can_create"
      },
      {
        value: "can_view"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const perm = {};
PermissionObj.permission.forEach(item =>
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, values]) => {
    perm[key] = values.map(x => x.value);
  })
);

const updated = data
  .map(item => {
    const newItem = {
      ...item
    };
    if (item.content) {
      newItem.content = item.content.filter(x =>
        perm[item.label].includes(x.value)
      );
    } else if (item.value) {
      newItem.value = perm[item.label].includes(item.value) ? item.value : "";
    }
    return newItem;
  })
  .filter(x => x.content || x.value);

console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Here is some problems if my data add additional two values For exmaple: { label: "Journals", content: [ { value: "can_create" }, { value: "can_view" }, { value: "can_edit" },{ value: "can_delete" } ] } , but I don't want to see can_delete and can_edit because permissions doesn't carry can_delete, can_edit  in journals . I want to compare with permissionobj with data .

Comment: I updated my code . can you see again

Comment: @sujon, oh got it, I just updated the answer. hope that helps.

Comment: I faced a problems if I filtering based on this objects  const PermissionObj = {
    permission: [
      {
        books: [
          {
            label: "Can View",
            value: "can_view"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
i can see there is a includes undefined

Comment: I just fixed this problem using by && operator  perm[item.label] && perm[item.label].includes(x.value). However , I facing another problem if I filter based on this format   const PermissionObj = {
    permission: [
      {
        books: [
          {
            label: "Can View",
            value: "can_view"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }; I just want to see this array of object inside data [{label:"books",value:"can_view"}]. However, I can see this format 
[{label:"books",value:"can_view"},
{label:"deal",content:[]},
{label:"Journals", content: []}]

Comment: if content is [], I don't want to show this object {label:"deal",content:[]}

Comment: can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106551/how-to-filtering-javascript-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

so you can get `keys` of the `permission` array, this would give you an array of keys.since you are getting the `keys` of an item in an array of objects so the `key` would always be the first item then you can check each data item with that key

```js
const PermissionObj = {
    permission: [
      {
        books: [
          {
            label: "Can View",
            value: "can_view"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Journals: [
          {
            label: "Can View",
            value: "can_view"
          },
          {
            label: "Can Create",
            value: "can_create"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        deal: [
          {
            label: "Can update",
            value: "can_update"
          },
          {
            label: "Can delete",
            value: "can_delete"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  const data = [
    {
      label: "books",
      value: "can_view"
    },
    {
      label: "deal",
      content: [
        {
          value: "can_update"
        },
        {
          value: "can_delete"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Articles"
    },
    {
      label: "Journals",
      content: [
        {
          value: "can_create"
        },
        {
          value: "can_view"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
    let permission = PermissionObj.permission;
    let NewData = [];
    permission.filter(item => {
      let ObjectKeys = Object.keys(item);
      let ObjKey = ObjectKeys[0];
      let DATA = data.find(
        dataItem => dataItem.label.toString() === ObjKey.toString()
      );
      NewData.push(DATA);
    });
    console.log(NewData);
```

Comment: Here is some problems if my data add additional two values For exmaple:    {
      label: "Journals",
      content: [
        {
          value: "can_create"
        },
        {
          value: "can_view"
        }, {
          value: "can_edit"
        },{
          value: "can_delete"
        }
      ]
    }  , but I don't want to see can_delete and can_edit because permissions doesn't carry can_delete, can_edit .

Comment: I updated my code . can you see again

Comment: can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106551/how-to-filtering-javascript-array-of-objects